# d3 xScale is broken

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, css-transitions

I'm splitting data into categories e.g. *rich poor and all*. Using dropdown to get those values to display on a scatterplot. First transition happens, everything works as expected. Text labels are correctly displayed too, however when another option is selected and second transition happened half of circles are disappearing and every other transition is messed up. Only works if option *all* selected than again, first transition works, after that it is all messed up.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/edgarkiljak/pen/ZmmNPM)

```
function render(someData) {

        xScale
            .domain([
                d3.min(someData, function(d) {
                    return +d.poorToys;
                }),
                d3.max(someData, function(d) {
                    return +d.poorToys;
                })
            ]);

        yScale
            .domain([
                d3.min(someData, function(d) {
                    return +d.richToys;
                }),
                d3.max(someData, function(d) {
                    return +d.richToys;
                })+ 20
            ]);

        //Adding circles
        var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(someData, function(d) {
                return d.country;
            });
```

I believe a problem starts here.

```
 circles
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            if (currentSelection === "rich") {
                return width - margin.right;
            } else if (currentSelection === "poor") {
                return margin.left;
            } else if (currentSelection === "all") {}
            return xScale(+d.poorToys);
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            if (currentSelection === "rich") {
                return margin.top;
            } else if (currentSelection === "poor") {
                return height - margin.bottom;
            } else if (currentSelection === "all") {}
            return yScale(+d.richToys);
        })
        .attr("r", function(d) {
            if (currentSelection === "all") {
                return rad;
            }
        })
        .style("fill", "red")

        .append("title")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.country + " reports books for " + d.poorToys + "% in poor areas and " + d.richToys + "% in rich areas.";
        });


    circles
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return xScale(+d.poorToys);
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return yScale(+d.richToys);
        })
        .attr("r", function() {
            if (currentSelection !== "all") {
                return rad * 1.5;
            } else {
                return rad;
            }
        });

    circles
        .exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .remove();

    //Update x axis
    svg.select(".x.axis")
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .call(xAxis);

    //Update y axis
    svg.select(".y.axis")
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .call(yAxis);


    if (currentSelection !== "all"){

        var labels = svg.selectAll("text.labels")
            .data(someData, function(d){
                return d.country;
            });

        labels
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", function(d){
                return "translate(" + xScale(+d.poorToys) + "," + yScale(+d.richToys) + ")";
            })
            .attr("dx", 2)
            .attr("dy", 1)
            .attr("class", "labels")
            .style("fill", "white")
            .style("font-size", "5px")
            .text(function(d){
                return d.country;
            });

        labels
            .transition()
            .duration(2000)
            .style("opacity", 1);


       labels
        .exit()
        .remove(); 

        } else {
                svg.selectAll("text.labels")
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1000)
                    .style("opacity", 0)
                    .remove();


    }   

}
```

Comment: why is `currentSelection` used in the positioning of the circles? Why convert numbers to numbers `+d.richToys`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that is more descriptive of your problem. "x is broken" is rarely something someone will search for and find your exact issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incorrectly give your x axis a class of `x_axis` on line 57 then later try to select it as `x.axis` in your render function on line 179.

Once you fix that up, I think it should work as expected.

```
svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + -14 + "," + (height + 30) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
```

[Updated Pen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/qQLyaB)

Comment: it is `x_axis` not `a_axis`

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the axis problem found by @ksav your main problem is that you don't position the labels. Many labels are present in rich and poor.

```
    var labels = svg.selectAll("text.labels")
        .data(someData, function(d){ return d.country; });

    labels
      .enter()
      .append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d){ return xScale(+d.poorToys); })
        .attr("y", function(d){ return yScale(+d.richToys); })
        .attr("dx", 2)
        .attr("dy", 1)
        .attr("class", "labels")
        .attr("opacity", 0)
        .style("fill", "white")
        .style("font-size", "8px")
        .text(function(d){ return d.country; })
      .merge(labels)
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .attr("x", function(d){ return xScale(+d.poorToys); })
        .attr("y", function(d){ return yScale(+d.richToys); })
        .attr("opacity", 1);
```

Also don't position the circles based on the selection

```
circles
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(+d.poorToys); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(+d.richToys); })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return rad; })
    .style("fill", "red")
    .append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.country + " reports books for " + d.poorToys + "% in poor areas and " + d.richToys + "% in rich areas.";
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Much appreciated.